# Javascript scrolling text

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using some javascript to scroll some text on my web page. Here is the link: http://javascript.about.com/library/bltick2.htm - (I tried pasting the code into this message, but had some difficulty with it).

This line of code sets the width: `var tWidth='300px';`

My question is this: How can I set this to be the size of the browser window... basically to set the text to scroll from one side of the page to another?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tWidth = window.innerWidth + 'px';
```

Or

```
var tWidth = '100%';
```

Thanks to JKing for the revisions.

Comment: window.innerWidth returns the value as a number, so the asker will probably want to add "px" to it to be more in line with his initial "300px" value.

Comment: I'm sure the user can figure that part out themself.

Comment: alternatively, you might try `var tWidth = "100%";`

Comment: @Dave: That's slightly immature. My answer is not incorrect and does not belong in a comment. Of course, JKing makes an important point, and in fact, I'm editing to reflect that.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I merely commented, don't be so quick to assume. Even though i know you down voted mine.

Comment: Haha, okay. Could've fooled me (and it still was a tad vindictive). My apologies nonetheless, Dave!

Comment: Haha, thanks for the acknowledgement, Elliot. I would have just edited your answer, but I didn't want to steal the credit...

Comment: vindictive only because i don't know why mine was either, solely because i hit enter before finishing my text by mistake so i wanted to know why mine was lol

Comment: @Dave: The only problem with your defense is that hitting enter in the answer text field only creates a new line. You'd have to manually click 'submit' in order to submit the answer. :)

Comment: Not for me - its always done it I have to shift enter every time. It happens alot but thank fully theres an edit button ^_^, this has gone some what off topic anyway now.